# Headphone Phone Jack Credit Card Swipe with Browser App

Tags: android, iphone, credit-card, mobile-browser

We want to accept credit card swipes via iPhone and Android phones but cannot find any devices that connect via the headphone jack that will populate a field in the phone's browser.  This is very easy to do with USB devices connected to a PC.

There are several existing phone jack devices with proprietary API's but from what I can tell these require native applications.  It makes sense for this to be standardized or for there to be an open source API but maybe the market isn't there yet.

Does anyone know of a way to get a headphone jack credit card swiper to populate a field in the phone's browser?

EDIT: This doesn't seem possible.  For some reason no one has a problem with using HID 
standard USB readers for PC's / Macs, but this is not ok for phones and tablets.  So the best option appears to be to to use PhoneGap to connect to a low cost reader.

But here's the problem: Readers choices appear to be $50-100 devices or $5 devices from China that we can't get to work reliably.  I'm looking for a reliable device in the $15-20 range and will be posting my research as tenable answers.

Comment: At least in the US, there are strict regulations about credit card acceptance. This may scare away smaller outfits and/or open source projects, due to liability concerns. For a ridiculously long list of validated software, try the [PCI SSC site.](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/approved_companies_providers/validated_payment_applications.php?agree=true) That may give you some place to start.

Comment: There are plenty other uses for magnetic stripe cards, including just generic ID cards, etc that would not involve the liability of credit card security. Is there anything that would read just a regular magnetic stripe card (not credit card) into a field?

Comment: Did you ever get a answer to this question?

Comment: Did you find anything useful by now? i'm at a loss!

Answer (score 2):

Have a peek at UniMag II, Two-Track Secure Mobile MagStripe Reader.

Comment: This device is too expensive at $40+  I've been watching the price of this device for over a year and am surprised the cost hasn't gone down more.

Answer (score 1):

RoamData offers a [PhoneGap plugin](http://www.roamdata.com/products/tools/roampay-phonegap-plugin/) to connect with their devices: [the RP350x](http://www.roamdata.com/products/hardware/rp350x-chip-sign-mobile-card-reader/) or [the device used by Group On](https://groupon-pos.myshopify.com/collections/basics/products/roampay-credit-card-swipe)

Still collecting information on these devices...

Comment: Do you know more about this phonegap plugin? I visited the link you provided but their site returned "product not found"

Answer (score 0):

Magtek has the iDynamo for $100 and the uDynamo for > $100.  I'm sure discounts are offered for volume discounts but this is pretty pricey.

http://www.magtek.com/V2/products/secure-card-reader-authenticators/index.asp